# Issue with KeyError: 'babel'

Tags: html, flask, datatable

I am very new to Flask and everything related to Web development. I am building an app in Flask with Dash integrated and it is failing with the following error:

```
C:\Users\satpute\PycharmProjects\RMAPartsDepotPlanning\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/PycharmProjects/RMAPrototype/dashapp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\dashapp.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\PDP\__init__.py", line 12, in create_app
    from PDP import PDPApp
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\PDP\PartsDepotPlanningApp.py", line 14, in <module>
    from flask_table import Table, Col, LinkCol
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_table\__init__.py", line 1, in 
<module>
    from .table import Table, create_table
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_table\table.py", line 8, in 
<module>
    from .columns import Col
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_table\columns.py", line 161, in 
<module>
    class BoolCol(OptCol):
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_table\columns.py", line 166, in 
BoolCol
    yes_display = _('Yes')
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_babel\__init__.py", line 548, in 
gettext
    t = get_translations()
   File "C:\PycharmProjects\RMAPrototype\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_babel\__init__.py", line 217, 
in get_translations
    babel = current_app.extensions['babel']
KeyError: 'babel'

> Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I go about troubleshooting this? I tried different approaches but couldn't resolve it so far.

Comment: How you initialize the Flask-Babel extension?